# What's the protocol tag for? Should it be deleted?

Tags: discussion, tagging

Could the [protocol](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/protocol) tag be deleted?

It seems that questions in this area will relate to a specific protocols, or set of protocols. E.g. [devp2p](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/devp2p) [rlpx](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/rlpx)

Comment: The tag was created on first day of private beta for [this question](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/259/87) asking about the _Ethereum Protocol_.

Answer (score 3):

I think this is like the [api](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/api) tag, which I am also in favor of deleting. What specific question could actually have "protocol" as a *meaningful* delimeter? If nothing else, protocol-design seems like it would catch many of the related questions.